# diff ignore blank likes

Tags: diff

How can I get GNU diff ignore the blank lines in the following example?

File a:

```
x
do

done
```

File b:

```
x

do
done
```

Neither file has trailing white spaces in any line.

Using GNU diff 3.1 on Mac OS X I get:

```
diff -w a b
2d1
< do
3a3
> do
```

Same when I add various promising looking options:

```
diff --suppress-blank-empty -E -b -w -B -I '^[[:space:]]*$' --strip-trailing-cr -i a b
2d1
< do
3a3
> do
```

What am I missing here?

```
diff --version
diff (GNU diffutils) 3.1
```

Comment: I have the same problem/question. Neither `-bBw` or any of the full arguments is ignoring blank lines or white spaces. Did you come up with a solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that diff is seeing `do` as being removed from the first file, and added to the second, maybe because there isn't enough context around the change.

If you reverse the order of the files as arguments, diff reports that the space is added and removed, and will then ignore it with `--ignore-blanks-lines`.

Looking at it as a unified diff, this is a little more clear:

```
$ diff test.txt test2.txt -u
--- test.txt    2015-10-20 10:50:52.585167600 -0700
+++ test2.txt   2015-10-20 10:51:01.042167600 -0700
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 x
-do

+do
 done

prp@QW7PRP09-14 ~/temp
$ diff test2.txt test.txt -u
--- test2.txt   2015-10-20 10:51:01.042167600 -0700
+++ test.txt    2015-10-20 10:50:52.585167600 -0700
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 x
-
 do
+
 done
```

And the result with the --ignore-blank-lines, and the order switched:

```
prp@QW7PRP09-14 ~/temp
$ diff test2.txt test.txt -B -u
```

Comment: Still seems odd that diff isn't independent of the order of the arguments, i.e., I'd expect that if `diff a b` is "no differences" then `diff b a` should say the same.